# tbb::parallel_for_each not executing while canceling

Tags: c++, tbb, cancellation

I'm running `tbb::parallel_for_each` deep within a `task_group`. The `task_group` is being canceled and that seems to cause `tbb::parallel_for_each` to exit without satisfying its postcondition. Here's minimal test case:

```
tbb::task_group g;
std::vector<int> x { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
std::atomic<std::size_t> counter {0};
g.run([&x, &counter]() {
    std::cout << "in run()\n" << std::flush;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
    std::cout << "in run(): slept\n" << std::flush;
    assert(tbb::task::self().is_cancelled());

    tbb::parallel_for_each(x, [&counter](int& y) {
        std::cout << "in run(): in parallel_for_each\n" << std::flush;
        ++y;
        ++counter;
    });
    assert(counter == x.size());
});
std::cout << "canceling\n" << std::flush;
g.cancel();
std::cout << "canceled " << g.is_canceling() << " " << tbb::task::self().is_cancelled() << std::endl;
assert(g.is_canceling());
std::cout << "canceled " << g.is_canceling() << " " << tbb::task::self().is_cancelled() << std::endl;
g.wait();
std::cout << "canceled " << g.is_canceling() << " " << tbb::task::self().is_cancelled() << std::endl;
```

That is: It has `tbb::task_group` call `run` on a function that waits for 0.1 s, then loops over a vector. It counts how many iterations that loop does. It then `cancel()`s the task group. The output is

```
canceling
in run()
canceled 1 0
canceled 1 0
in run(): slept
Assertion failed: (counter == x.size()), function operator(), file test.cpp
```

That's to say that the inner loop never happens. My surprise, though, is that `tbb::parallel_for_each` is called and exits without exception, but its post-condition (of doing the loop) isn't met!

1. Is that the expected behavior? The docs don't give any caveats: https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506160
2. How do I check for this behavior? Do I always have to check `tbb::task::self().is_cancelled()` after calling `tbb::parallel_for_each` if I want to be sure it actually did its job?
3. Shouldn't `tbb::parallel_for_each` throw an exception in this case (or at least return `bool`)?

I can "fix" this by using an isolated context (https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506075) like this:

```
    tbb::task_group_context root(tbb::task_group_context::isolated);
    tbb::parallel_for_each(x, [&counter](int& y) {
        std::cout << "in run(): in parallel_for_each\n" << std::flush;
        ++y;
        ++counter;
    }, root);
```

but at the moment, I'm not sure when I can ever trust `tbb::parallel_for_each` to do its job.

Comment: I added https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/issues/253 as a tbb issue

Answer (score 1):

Within a task group, calls to `tbb::parallel_for_each` are subordinate to the task group's context.

Cancelling that task group cancels it, and all subordinate task groups.  I cannot find where in the docs "subordinate task group" is defined, but it appears to be groups under the group in the "task tree".

A cancelled `tbb::parallel_for_each` does not guarantee that all of its iterations are complete.  No post condition was violated.

You cancelled the task group, which cancels the subordinate `tbb::parallel_for_each`'s implicit task group, so it doesn't do the operations.

Your isolated context prevents the cancellation from propagating into the parallel for each's task group.  You can replicate the effect in that code by canceling `root` prior to calling `parallel_for_each`.

Comment: Thank you. This is the conclusion I came to.

Are there other conditions besides `tbb::task::self().is_cancelled()` under which `tbb::parallel_for_each` would not do all it is asked to do? As in, is it sufficient to check `tbb::task::self().is_cancelled()` after `tbb::parallel_for_each`?

Given that it's not documented directly in the `tbb::parallel_for_each` page, it really feels to me like something that should be an exception.